# gsub to return all matches of an expression instead of just the last match

Tags: r, regex

I'm looking for a gsub string that will return all matches of an expression, rather than just the last match.  i.e.:

```
data <- list("a sentence with citation (Ref. 12) and another (Ref. 13)", "single (Ref. 14)")
gsub(".*(Ref. (\\d+)).*", "\\1", data)
```

Returns

```
[1] "Ref. 13" "Ref. 14"
```

so I've lost Ref. 12.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `strapply` function from the `gsubfn` package to do this:

```
library(gsubfn)

data <- list("a sentence with citation (Ref. 12) and another (Ref. 13)", "single (Ref. 14)") 
unlist(strapply(data,"(Ref. (\\d+))"))
```

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
sapply(data,stringr::str_extract_all,pattern="Ref. (\\d+))")
```

?

Comment: Nice. I figured that this had to have been implemented somewhere else before. (Also interesting to see that `str_extract_all` in turn calls `str_locate_all`, which calls `re_mapply("gregexpr", string, pattern)` -- as nice a pseudocode summary of my function as I could imagine).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function -- essentially a wrapper for `gregexpr()` -- that will capture multiple references from a single string.

```
extractMatches <- function(data, pattern) {
    start <-  gregexpr(pattern, data)[[1]]
    stop  <-  start + attr(start, "match.length") - 1
    if(-1 %in% start) {
        ""    ## **Note** you could return NULL if there are no matches 
    } else {
        mapply(substr, start, stop, MoreArgs = list(x = data))
    }
}    

data <- list("a sentence with citation (Ref. 12), (Ref. 13), and then (Ref. 14)",
             "another sentence without reference")
pat <- "Ref. (\\d+)"

res <- lapply(data, extractMatches, pattern = pat)
res
# [[1]]
# [1] "Ref. 12" "Ref. 13" "Ref. 14"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] ""
```

(** Note **: If you return `NULL` instead of `""` when there is no reference in a string, then you can post-process the results with `do.call("c", res)` to get a single vector containing just the matching references).

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem before (http://thebiobucket.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-extract-citation-from-body-of.html) and came up with this (in fact very close to ben's) solution:

```
require(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(unlist(data), pattern = "\\(.*?\\)"))
```

giving:

```
[1] "(Ref. 12)" "(Ref. 13)" "(Ref. 14)"
```